# Fazer consulta a dados de usuario

Tags: wordpress, query, plugin

Olá, gostaria de saber se há possibilidade de fazer consultas a atributos do usuários e exibir na tela. Para fazer o cadastro do usuário estou utilizando o plugin *member final*, que por padrão só exibe a foto e login do usuário, entretanto queria exibir mais dados após a pesquisa.

Algum poderia me ajudar ?

Ate o momento está [dessa forma](https://snag.gy/ZKfjLk.jpg).

Gostaria de conseguir incluir mais coisa para deixar [igual a isso](https://snag.gy/58qCXK.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém necessite segue o código:

Só achar a variável criada no formulário e alterar para retornar o que necessita.
Arquivo dentro do plugin editado templates/members-grid.php

```
<ul class="um-memberColoDsc">
                                <li class="espMemR"><a href="<?php echo um_user_profile_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo um_user('nome'); ?>"><?php echo um_user('regiao'); ?></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo um_user_profile_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo um_user('nome'); ?>"><?php echo um_user('phone_number'); ?></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo um_user_profile_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo um_user('nome'); ?>"><?php echo um_user('user_email'); ?></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo um_user_profile_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo um_user('nome'); ?>"><?php echo um_user('site'); ?></a></li>
                            </ul>
```